# T-SQL Cursors alternate in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, database-cursor

I have a stored procedure written in T-SQL which uses cursors but now I want to use it in Google BigQuery. I am re-writing the query in GBQ but don't know how to convert cursor logic because bigquery doesn't support it. Below is the T-SQL script which I want to convert into BigQuery:

```
DECLARE
    @query              cursor,
    @wm_query           cursor,

    @passenger_id       varchar(48),
    @trip_no            nvarchar(255),
    @created_at         datetime2(7) ,
    @prev_cash_balance  numeric(18,5),
    @prev_promo_balance numeric(18,5),
    @_id                nvarchar(255)

SET @query = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT passenger_id, trip_no, created_at, _id
    FROM source_wallet
    ORDER BY passenger_id, created_at, _id

OPEN @query
FETCH NEXT FROM @query INTO @passenger_id, @trip_no, @created_at, @_id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @wm_query = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        select top 1 cash_balance, promo_balance from wallet_master where passenger_id = @passenger_id 
        order by created_at desc, _id desc

            OPEN @wm_query
            FETCH NEXT FROM @wm_query into @prev_cash_balance, @prev_promo_balance

                insert into wallet_master (passenger_id, created_at, cash_usage, promo_usage, _id)
                select @passenger_id, @created_at, case<some logic>, case<some logic>, _id

            CLOSE @wm_query
            deallocate @wm_query
        FETCH NEXT FROM @query into @passenger_id, @trip_no, @created_at, @_id          
    END
CLOSE @query
DEALLOCATE @query
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to rewrite your code to BigQuery at first due to the lack of dummy data and inability to reproduce the case. However, I can give you the pointers to start re-writing your code.

**1st)** You can make use of temporary tables with ***WITH*** *clause* in BigQuery to make transformations in your data, instead of using **FAST_FORWARD FOR**. The standard ***SQL Query Syntax*** can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax). Furthermore, I would like to point that you can have multiple temporary tables at once.

**2nd)** According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#loops), it is possible to use scripting within BigQuery. Thus, ***LOOPS*** are available with various built-in methods.

**3rd)** In addition, the ***IF*** syntax is also available in BigQuery, you can find the proper documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#if).

**4th)** I also encourage you to have a look at teh ***DECLARE*** and ***SET*** [statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare), which could help with the creation and manipulation of variables, it must be pointed that you can not use parameterized variables as table names in BigQuery.

**5th)** I believe this [article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) would also help to understand parameterization in BigQuery.

I encourage you to start writing you code in BigQuery, then if you have any other questions you can ask here.

Let me know if if you need any more help. I hope it was useful.